# How to display/ hide some portion of the form on radio button selection in android?

Tags: android

I have a requirement where the form has to ask "do you  have valid license:" and in radio choice 1)yes 2)no . on selection of yes  the fields to fill licenseno. , licensee_name and take license photo should  appear and  on selection of no these thing should  be hidden and it should continue with filling of the rest of the form fields .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your concern try like this

Get Radio button like this :

```
RadioButton rbone = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rone);
RadioButton rbtwo = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rtwo);
```

Get Radio Group like this

```
radioGroup = (RadioGroup) dialog.findViewById(R.id.rg);
```

And then fallow like this

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (rbone.isChecked() == true) {
                    view1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    view2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }else{
                    view2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    view1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                            }
                        });
```

Comment: when i tried your code i got error in setOnCheckedChangeListener which says "The method setOnCheckedChangeListener(RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener) in the type RadioGroup is not applicable for the arguments (new OnCheckedChangeListener(){})"

Comment: hey it worked for me only thing is that i need to change the import.

Comment: hey it worked for me only thing is that i need to change the import. now i have some fields in a tablelayout where one option is to take photo the moment i take photo the page refreshes and the tablelayout again hides. after taking the photo the page should not refresh.

Comment: Simply OnClick of button (which initiates picture taking part).. set   "table_layout.setVisibility(View.GONE)" and "new_layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);" . Please accept answer if it works for you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to write the child View Like licenseno and name and photo inside one layout and give one id to that layout the programmatically you can hide visibility of that block.

Like :

```
LinearLayout ly=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.LayoutID);

    ly.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            OR
    ly.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

According to Your Radio Button Click Event you can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can set view.VISIBLE and view.INVISIBLE for controls to visible and invisible

Comment: ya shivani  may be it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. If your radio buttons belongs to the same group

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if(checkedId == R.id.radioYes){
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else if(checkedId == R.id.radioNo){
                // Depends of your requirement
                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                     // or
                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    });
```